# Call Laravel Model Function from Blade Button OnClick Javascript Function and Stay On the Page

Tags: javascript, laravel, model, onclick, laravel-blade

Goal:

A user will have a list of games in a table with text boxes for each team's score. I want the user to be able to change the score of a single game, click Save (Model function updates the record), and continue saving more games while never leaving the page.

[image]

How:

After a Laravel Blade view has been rendered, I want to execute a Model function from a Javascript function on-button-click, but stay on the same page.

**admin.blade.php** (Javascript section in Head tag)

```
/* Save game from inline list on Admin page */
function inlineSaveAdmin(gameId) {
  var homeScoreTxt = document.getElementById("homeScoreTxtBox");
  var homeScore = homeScoreTxt.value;
  var awayScoreTxt = document.getElementById("awayScoreTxtBox");
  var awayScore = awayScoreTxt.value;

  {{ App\Models\Game::inlineSave(gameId, homeScore, awayScore) }}
}
```

**admin.blade.php** (body of view)

```
<button type="button" onclick="inlineSaveAdmin({{ $game->id }});" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
```

So far, the Model function only executes when the page loads, not when I click the button. That is the main problem I wish to solve. Thanks for any help!

(and yes, I believe that I will need to create identical Javascript functions for each gameId that exists to be able to reference the correct homeScoreTxtBox{{ game->id }} since I don't think I could otherwise dynamically pull the text box IDs based on the Javascript function's input parameter)

Comment: you can achieve this using ajax but you have to specify the function in controller instead of model @thePlTman

Answer (score 1):

1.make an ajax function on that blade file

2.call that ajax `on click` pass the id and updated data

3.define a route for that ajax function in `web.php` and

4.make a controller function on that route.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").on('click', function() {
                 **//get id and score**
var homeScoreTxt = document.getElementById("homeScoreTxtBox");
var homeScore = homeScoreTxt.value;
var awayScoreTxt = document.getElementById("awayScoreTxtBox");
var awayScore = awayScoreTxt.value;
var game_id = gameId;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: '{{ route('update') }}',
//all the data you need to pass to controller function
                        data: {       
                            'id': gameId,
                            'homescore': homeScore,
                            'awayscore' : awayScore
                        },
                        // dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            //data returned from php
                            // update the values 
                            if (data) {
                                homeScoreTxt.value=data.homeScore,
                                awayScoreTxt.value=data.homeScore
                            }
                        },
                        fail: function() {
                            alert('NO');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('update', 'UpdateController@update')->name('update');
```

Update the values in the controller function by simple model queries.
Send updated data like this:

```
$response = [
    'homeScore' => $homeScore,
    'awayScore' => $awayScore
];

return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: When I click the button, it successfully calls my JavaScript function. However, when it gets into the Ajax call, it results in an error, displaying the Alert I have in my error: function() section. If I am reading Google Debug correctly, it tried to do the following lines in jQuery: try { completed = false; transport.send( requestHeaders, done ); } Then the error message appears to be at this line: xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ); The error message is: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: function inlineSave(gameId) {
    var saveBtn = document.getElementById("SaveBtn"+gameId);
    var homeScoreTxt = document.getElementById("homeScoreTxtBox"+gameId);
    var homeScore = homeScoreTxt.value;
    var awayScoreTxt = document.getElementById("awayScoreTxtBox"+gameId);
    var awayScore = awayScoreTxt.value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('inlineSave') }}",
      type: "POST",
      requestHeaders: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      //all the data you need to pass to controller function

Comment: data: {
        'gameId' : gameId,
        'homeScore': homeScore,
        'awayScore' : awayScore
      },
      dataType: "json",
      traditional: true,
      success: function(data) {
        //data returned from php
        // update the values 
        if (data) {
          homeScoreTxt.value = data.homeScore,
          awayScoreTxt.value = data.awayScore
          saveBtn.innerText = 'Resave';
          alert('Success!');
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('An error has occurred!');
      }
    });
  }

Comment: You don't need to call any other JS function just give the button an id and use in jQuery like `$("#ID").on('click', function() {` in above mentioned code second line.debug it line by line using `console.log` that where is the problem.

Comment: Is it required to use jQuery like you showed to define the function? I can do that, but I'd need to do a @foreach and dynamically create 1 function per button (which is easy, it just results in inflated lines of unnecessary code if using the JavaScript function is equivalent). But if it MUST be a jQuery function definition (not JavaScript) in order for the Ajax call to work, I can do that. (I'll get to this tonight)

Comment: Here's an example with JS using ajax you should check it out:   `https://dev.to/nikola/making-ajax-calls-in-pure-javascript-the-old-way-ed5#:~:text=To%20use%20AJAX%20in%20JavaScript,open%20the%20request` but i would recommend using jQuery.

Comment: I have changed it to jQuery instead of JavaScript. I am still getting an error. I posted a new "answer" on this thread so that I could go into detail with my debugging, and where my code is currently. Thank you for all your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed Daniyal Ishaq's answer, and I think I'm getting closer, but I'm getting an error from the Ajax call.

Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
(jquery-3.5.1.js:10099) xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

Per Google debugger, it appears to be after/inside this call:

```
(jquery-3.5.1.js:9682) transport.send( requestHeaders, done );
```

I did some debugging, and a "status" variable is getting set to 500. Then, "isSuccess" is set to False when it gets to this line:

```
(jquery-3.5.1.js:9723) isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
```

That line that sets isSuccess is inside the following function, but I cannot seem to find where it's getting called from to trace where status is getting set exactly.

```
(jquery-3.5.1.js:9696) function done( status, nativeStatusText, responses, headers ) {
```

The last line I can find before the error appears is 5233:

```
(jquery-3.5.1.js:5233) jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
```

Shortly before that line, it is here, where event.rnamespace = undefined, and handleObj.namespace = "" (I don't know if this is relevant):

```
(jquery-3.5.1.js:5422) if ( !event.rnamespace || handleObj.namespace === false ||
```

Shortly after that, "ret" is still undefined after this line: (again, I don't know what this does, but it seems important?)

```
ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle ||
    handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );
```

Then on 5446, it returns event.result, which is undefined.

```
return event.result;
```

That is where my debugging skills hit a dead end with jQuery. So now I ask for more help.

Ajax function in blade:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
@foreach($games as $game)
  $("#SaveBtn{{ $game->id }}").on('click', function() {
    var gameId = "{{ $game->id }}";
    var saveBtn = document.getElementById("SaveBtn{{ $game->id }}");
    var homeScoreTxt = document.getElementById("homeScoreTxtBox{{ $game->id }}");
    var homeScore = homeScoreTxt.value;
    var awayScoreTxt = document.getElementById("awayScoreTxtBox{{ $game->id }}");
    var awayScore = awayScoreTxt.value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('inlineSave') }}",
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      //all the data you need to pass to controller function
      data: {
        'gameId' : {{ $game-> id }},
        'homeScore': homeScore,
        'awayScore' : awayScore
      },
      dataType: "json",
      traditional: true,
      success: function(data) {
        //data returned from php
        // update the values 
        if (data) {
          homeScoreTxt.value = data.homeScore;
          awayScoreTxt.value = data.awayScore;
          saveBtn.innerText = 'Resave';
          alert('Success!');
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('An error has occurred!');
      }
    });
  });
@endforeach
});
```

Resulting HTML for Ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SaveBtn11870").on('click', function() {
    var gameId = "11870";
    var saveBtn = document.getElementById("SaveBtn11870");
    var homeScoreTxt = document.getElementById("homeScoreTxtBox11870");
    var homeScore = homeScoreTxt.value;
    var awayScoreTxt = document.getElementById("awayScoreTxtBox11870");
    var awayScore = awayScoreTxt.value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mbcathletics/admin",
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      //all the data you need to pass to controller function
      data: {
        'gameId' : 11870,
        'homeScore': homeScore,
        'awayScore' : awayScore
      },
      dataType: "json",
      traditional: true,
      success: function(data) {
        //data returned from php
        // update the values 
        if (data) {
          homeScoreTxt.value = data.homeScore;
          awayScoreTxt.value = data.awayScore;
          saveBtn.innerText = 'Resave';
          alert('Success!');
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('An error has occurred!');
      }
    });
  });

... many more of the same function for different button IDs ...
});
```

Button in blade: (calls its respective function successfully)

```
<button id="SaveBtn{{ $game->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
```

Route in web.php: (remember, I do not want to leave the page, I just want it to execute the Controller function... I don't know what to put in the first parameter - the URL)

```
Route::post('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'inlineSave'])->name('inlineSave');
```

Controller function: (it doesn't really do anything right now, I'm just trying to test connectivity before I do the heavy lifting)

```
public static function inlineSave()
{
  $game = Game::find($gameId);
  $score = $game->home_score;
  $game->home_score = $score;

  $response = [
    'homeScore' => $homeScore,
    'awayScore' => $awayScore
  ];

  return response()->json($response);
}
```

Thank you! I am sorry for the detail, but it's the only I know how to help.